# JQuery/javascript only works on Chrome, not IE or FF

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser, slideshow

I have a JQuery slideshow on this webpage http://www.2eenheid.de/cloud/.

This javascript only works right on Chrome though, but not FF or IE. Something wrong in my code or something else?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
            var imgsrc = '';
            var newImg = '';
            imgsrc = $('.pikachoose').css('background-image');

            $('#slideshow-main ul.slideshow-menu').find('a').hover(function () {
                newImg = $(this).attr('src');
                new_imgsrc=imgsrc.replace('url(','').replace(')','');

                if (newImg === new_imgsrc){
                    return;
                }

                $('.pikachoose').stop().fadeOut('fast', function () {
                    $(this).css({
                        'background-image': 'url(' + newImg + ')'
                    }).fadeTo('slow', 1);
                });



            }, function () {


                if (newImg === new_imgsrc){
                    return;
                }


                $('.pikachoose').stop().fadeOut('fast', function () {
                    $(this).css({
                        'background-image': imgsrc 
                    }).fadeTo('slow', 1);
                });
            });

        }); 
    </script>
```

Comment: works for me on ie 9 (v 9.0.8112.16421), ff 16 (16.0.2).

Comment: Seems to work ok for me on FF as well, what are you expecting it to do, and what is it doing

Comment: In Chrome when for example on page 'Cloud' it stops the fading when the background image is the same as the image its going to fade to. It does this in Chrome, but doesn't do this in IE and FF here.. Or does this work in your browsers too?

Comment: I'm talking about this piece of code `     new_imgsrc=imgsrc.replace('url(','').replace(')','');
     
     if (newImg === new_imgsrc){
      return;
     }`

Comment: And have you tried logging what those values are. `new_imgsrc` and `newImg`?

Comment: `alert(new_imgsrc)` and `alert(newImg)` above where you compare them

Comment: I added the alert, you can look and see. It prints out the same link but one with "" quotes and one without. Could that be a problem?

Comment: Yes if you are doing an explicit check `===` which order are you alerting the variables in. Also try changing the `newImg === new_imgsrc` to just `==`. and also take the alerts off now.

Comment: I tried changing to `==` but still not working in FF or IE?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34686/discussion-between-casii-iisac-and-mark-walters)

Comment: It works now! Changed the replace code to `new_imgsrc=imgsrc.replace(/url\(("|'|)|("|'|)\)/g,'');`